# Nested reactive form always valid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I use nested reactive form as FormControl.

Here is demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmfq5z?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Issue: the main form is valid even if nested is invalid (try to clear required fields).

How the main form can be notified about nested form validity change?

The main form component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ControlContainer, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <pre>Valid: {{ form.valid }}</pre>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" novalidate>
      <label>name</label>
      <input formControlName="name">
      <app-address-form formControlName="address"></app-address-form>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
    <ng-container *ngIf="submitData">
      <span>submit data</span>
      <pre>{{ submitData }}</pre>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  submitData = '';
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: fb.control('foo bar', Validators.required),
      address: fb.control({
        city: 'baz',
        town: 'qux',
      })
    });
  }

  onSubmit(v: any) {
    this.submitData = JSON.stringify(v, null, 2);
  }
}
```

The nested form component:

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, ControlValueAccessor, FormGroup, FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgControl, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

// https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vTS20UdnMGqA3ecrv7ww_7CDKQM8VgdH2tbHl94aXgEsYQ2cyjq62ydU3e3ZF_BaQ64kMyQa0INe2oI/pub?slide=id.g293d7d2b9d_1_1532
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-form',
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="form">
      <label>city</label>
      <input formControlName="city" (blur)="onTouched()">
      <label>town</label>
      <input formControlName="town" (blur)="onTouched()">
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressFormComponent)
    }
  ]
})
export class AddressFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    town: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  onTouched: () => void = () => {};

  writeValue(v: any) {
    this.form.setValue(v, { emitEvent: false });
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (v: any) => void) {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    disabled ? this.form.disable() : this.form.enable();
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

Comment: emit event_emitter from child to parent. you can update the parent form validators using setValidators()

Comment: could you provide more details, please?

Comment: Provided answer below.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10530

Answer (score 1):

**Approach1: (using Event Emitter)**

```
export class AddressFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
   @Output formValidStatus = new EventEmitter<any>();

   this.formValidStatus.emit(true);
}
```

**Parent Component Template:**

```
<app-address-form (formValidStatus)="formValidStatus($event)" formControlName="address"></app-address-form>
```

**Parent Component :**

```
formValidStatus(){
  //update form status
}
```

**Approach2:**

Inject ParentComponent inside Child Component constructor using Angular DI. You can call parent methods in child component.

```
constructor(private appc: AppComponent){} 

this.appc.methodname();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your address control to formGroup and add validation there as well

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: fb.control('foo bar', Validators.required),
      address: fb.control({
        city: 'baz',
        town: 'qux',
      })
    });
  }
```

So it should be:

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: fb.control('foo bar', Validators.required),
      address: fb.group({
        city: ['box',Validators.required],
        town: ['qux',Validators.required],
      })
    });
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/save-7ucjtn

Comment: The main form won't be aware of dynamically added controls in the nested component.

Comment: Not bad so far. But still there's an error.
Error: control.registerOnChange is not a function

Comment: My issue is the opposite. it is always invalid even though the form controls are all valid.

Comment: @chitgoks issue is not clear to me if you can update the details or send a email to me